# Android - use picasso to load image without storing it in cache

Tags: android, picasso

I want to use picasso to load an image from a url into a placeholder, but not store that image in cache - in other words, I want the image to be downloaded from the net directly to disk and then loaded from disk when needed. I understand there's a class called RequestCreator where you can specify memory policy - does anyone have an example of using picasso/requestcreator to do something like this?

So.. something like:

```
RequestCreator requestCreator = new RequestCreator();
requestCreator.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE);
....
```

merged with:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(someurl).fit().placeholder(someplaceholder).into(sometarget)..
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Picasso supports this by it's `skipMemoryCache()` in the Picasso builder. An example is shown below.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .skipMemoryCache()
                .into(imageView);
```

With the new API you should use it like this so that it skips looking for it and storing it in the cache:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl)
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .into(imageView);
```

`NO_CACHE`

> Skips memory cache lookup when processing a request.

`NO_STORE`

> Skips storing the final result into memory cache. Useful for one-off requests to avoid evicting other bitmaps from the cache.

Comment: How can we get cache image using Picaso asfter using No_Store

Comment: That's a whole other question, you should try searching for it and if you can't find a question then ask it

Answer (score 8):

For `picasso:2.71828` or above version use the following for skipping using disk cache `networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)`  :

```
  Picasso.get()
            .load(camera_url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loader2)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .into(img_cam_view);
```

Comment: `NetworkPolicy` regulates the disk cache as compared to MemoryPolicy which regulates the memory cache. Additionally `NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE` flag can also be used to skip storing the images on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso 2.5.0

If you are using Picasso to load image from Internet, you have to use NetworkPolicy attribute.

```
.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
```

but live memory cache (Not disk cache) is useful, you might want to keep it.

Answer (score -6):

just append this at the end of url.

```
"?=" + System.currentTimeMillis();
```