# Image is not loading when given placeholder : ANDROID

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-glide

Image is not loading when using a placeholder.

> Glide code

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(uri)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(view);
```

> Picasso code

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(uri)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(view);
```

I am using an adapter to load multiple image.

1. using **Picasso**  placeholder is not changing to original image.
2. using **Glide** placeholder is changing but original image is not coming.

But if I slide the adapter or refreshing then it will come.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glide not loading real image and stuck with placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384789/glide-not-loading-real-image-and-stuck-with-placeholder)

Comment: the problem with is picasso/Glide store image in cache memory  for better use and for that you put method to no memory cache this answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/30087215/8164071

Comment: @Sanoop I tried that , but no luck

Comment: please addd your view holder code or getview

Answer (score -1):

Try in this way..

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .load(uri)
            .into(view);
```

placeholder should be before the image is loaded.

Comment: Actually, .with() returns a different object to .load()

Comment: This does not work, because the object returned by `.with` does not have the `.placeholder` method